# A visuality gap between text box and it scroll bar

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I'm creating my first windows forms app.
I've added a text box to the form and forced it to have a vertical scroll bar, 
but it looks like there is a space between the text box and the scroll bar,
which of course does not look good:

[AS you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFT6T.png)

[Appearance of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKl8p.png)

I've searched online and tried to "play" with the margins around the text box but i couldn't solve it

thank you.

Comment: Are you using a form with a transparent background? (assuming you didn't add a textbox AND a scrollbar and there is a margin...)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer.I'm very new at windows forms app.
I've added a screen-shot of the appearance of the form:

Comment: "I'm creating my first windows forms app". It's 2019. You might want to consider a newer technology. It's easier to start from wpf than it is to move to wpf once you're used to winforms.

Comment: The screenshot of some from properties is not really helpful. Did you set TransparencyKey??

Comment: Hey, the transparency key is set to white

Comment: Any chance that the transparent area is actually...white?!

Comment: Hey,
Yes. the transparency key is white

Comment: Do not use TransparencyKey unless you have a reason; and if you, do try to avoid any color that will be in the normal controls or else you get what you got..

Answer (score 0):

I would try to resize the textbox (not in height but in length/width just to check if it changes anything). I had the same Issue once and could fix it with that.

~Fab